# Make a div Horizontally and Vertically Centered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new in twitter bootstrap 3.

I try to make a div horizontally and vertically centered.

What I have done is -

```
<!-- Content -->
    <div class="container outer_container">
        <div class="inner_container">
            <h1>Jumbotron heading</h1>
            <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Content -->
```

HTML Code.

And CSS code is -

```
    .outer_container
    {
    position:absolute !important;
    height:100% !important;
    width:100% !important;
       display: table !important;
   }

   .inner_container
   {
       display: table-cell !important;
       vertical-align: middle !important;
       text-align:center !important;
   }
```

And it gives a output like it-
[image: Output 1]

But If I add a ***col-sm-4*** class, then the code is-

HTML-

```
<!-- Content -->
    <div class="container outer_container">
        <div class="col-sm-4 inner_container">
            <h1>Jumbotron heading</h1>
            <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Content -->
```

And the CSS remains same-

```
.outer_container
   {
    position:absolute !important;
       height:100% !important;
       width:100% !important;
    display: table !important;
   }

   .inner_container
   {
    display: table-cell !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    text-align:center !important;
   }
```

But I get a output like-

[image: Output 2]

But I want to have a output like it-
[image: Desired Output]

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: I have also tried inline coding, but it didn't work.

Comment: Use  margin:0 auto; for your element if it works. Try it.

Comment: You have a `container` followed by a `col`. Correct hierarchy is `container` => `row` => `col-??-##`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To center it horizontally I would something like:

```
<div class="container outer-container">
    <div class="row inner-container">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
            <!-- Contents... You can change lg for any other size or add more sizes but remember to add the corresponding offset -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping.

But it does not work.

I have solved it.

Solution is given in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use this-

```
<!-- Content -->
    <div class="container outer_container">
        <div class="row-fluid inner_container">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
                <h1>Jumbotron heading</h1>
                <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Content -->
```

Answer (score 1):

There're [many ways](http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) to archive that. However, in your case, `.col-sm-4` produces 25% of its parent width. So why not just make your `.inner_container` 25%?

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row jumbo">
       <div class="outer-container">
           <div class="inner-container">
               <h1>Jumbotron heading</h1>
               <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>

.jumbo {
    display: table;
}
.outer-container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    height: 500px;
}
.inner-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
}
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5yz4bgy8/).

**Note: you are declaring too many `!important;`. I don't think you will need that much. Check if you have included your `bootstrap.css` before your main `stylesheet`.